# Stand Alone Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that I run from a system once a week, and the data is exported into an excel document.  I have set up the tool that exports the data to excel to do a decent job on formatting, but there is still more that I need to do once the data is in excel.

Is it possible to create a stand alone macro, save it in a Microsoft office folder and be able to call it after I open this file?  I have written plenty of macros that are part of ONE given spreadsheet, but never tried one that was open to many spreadsheets.

IS it possible, and a starting direction of good resources of where I can learn how to achieve this goal?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...and be able to call it after I open this file?...

You have 2 very good options

**1)** Write and save your macro to Personal file. See this link for more information

**Topic**: Deploy your Excel macros from a central file

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/deploy-your-excel-macros-from-a-central-file-HA001087296.aspx

**Quote from the above link**:

> Have you ever wanted to use that really handy macro in all of your Excel worksheets? You can. This column explains how to place your macros in a file called personal.xls and make them available each time you start Excel.

**2)** Create an Add-In

**Topic**: Creating an Excel Add-in

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140936%28v=office.10%29.aspx

**Quote from the above link**:

> You create a Microsoft® Excel add-in by creating a workbook, adding code and custom toolbars and menu items to it, and saving it as an Excel add-in file.