# VBA / Macro - How to avoid importing Module for Every file

Tags: excel, vba

I've build a personally needed `VBA module (macro)` successfully. However, the issue is that I have to use it in almost 100 different files all over the week on daily basis. Now I dont want to `import` the Module for every file. neither I want to add it as an `addin` everyday.

So, if anyone got a permanent solution which is a `just-once` solution (like a dll which will load with windows itself), please feel free to share.

Also note, I would want the shortcut key that I made for it to be preserved as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: put it in an `Add-in`

Comment: See this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251156/stand-alone-excel-macro

Comment: will it autoload next time?

Comment: If you add the add-in correctly it should load automatically yes.

Comment: Add it to `Personal.XLSB` file which open automatically each time you start Excel.

Comment: Save your excel file as addin and follow the following http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/installing-an-add-in-in-excel-2007/